# Sigma of factorial function?

Tags: summation, factorial

How would you find this sum mathmatically?$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) ^{i!}$$

What techniques would you use to solve this as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Liouville number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) It is transcendental.  As factorials grow extremely rapidly, it converges very fast.  I would sum a few terms (until you get tired) and call it good.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%281/2%29%5E%28n!%29%20from%200%20to%2010)gives 1.26562506...  I quit after $i=10$-it wouldn't do $15$.  As $11!=39,916,800$ these decimals should be good

Comment: Using Wolfram Alpha, I found the sum to be approximated to 1.26563. Can this number be say, some power of $e$ or $\pi$, that's found mathematically?

Comment: @VishwaIyer If this sum simplifies, then neither I nor Mathematica know how to do so. :-) But, like Ross said, this will converge INCREDIBLY quickly; even summing just a few terms will get you a very accurate approximation.

Comment: It is already written in binary.  Why do you want to write it in decimal?

Comment: @GEdgar:  Good question, but I am used to decimal, and I suspect I am not alone.

Comment: Once you have more than a three or four terms, every nonzero digit you get is _always_ good. Except for the first few terms, the first significant digit of each term comes _after_ the last decimal of the previous term.